# records showing in reverse order in mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

Sample data is below.

[image]

I am writing below query to fetch most recent 10 records.

```
SELECT * FROM `tblmessages` order by message_id desc limit 10
```

The issue is that it gives the result in reverse order.

My expected result set was from message id = 15 to message id = 24.

But, I am presently getting from message id = 24 to message id = 15. I meant, it shows in reverse order. Can you please suggest something?

here is Laravel eloquent of the query.

```
ThreadMessagesModel::where("thread_id", $thread_id)
                   ->orderBy("message_id", "desc")
                   ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: `select * from (SELECT * FROM tblmessages order by message_id desc limit 10) order by message_id asc`

Comment: _My expected result set was from message id = 15 to message id = 24.

But, I am presently getting from message id = 24 to message id = 15. I meant, it shows in reverse order. Can you please suggest something?_ I don't understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should run the following query.

```
Select * from (
                SELECT * FROM `tblmessages` order by message_id desc limit 10
              ) as a 
order by message_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT *
       FROM tblmessage 
       ORDER BY message_id DESC
       LIMIT 10
) main
ORDER BY main.message_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The results are displayed in reverse because the order by is `desc`ending. You could use the following query to get the highest id's sorted `asc`ding`

```
SELECT * FROM `tblmessages` 
WHERE message_id IN (
                        SELECT message_id 
                        FROM `tblmessages` 
                        order by message_id desc 
                        limit 10
                    )
```